# Permisos para acceso a la aplicación

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

Gente, una consulta.
Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Android con Firebase como base de datos, en la cual el usuario debe registarse con su cuenta de Google para acceder a todas las funciones y caracteristicas que tiene la aplicación.
Ya llené la ficha de play store.

En esta opción cúal debo escoger?
No estoy seguro de cuál escoger.
[image: acceso a la aplicación]

Answer (score 3):

Si tu aplicación no tiene contenido restringido, esto quiere decir que no requiere realizar una compra o suscripción para ingresar a alguno de sus contenidos debes seleccionar:

**"Todas las funciones están disponibles sin acceso especial"**

de lo contrario debes seleccionar :

**"Todas o algunas de las funciones están restringidas"**

al seleccionar esta opción es importante proporcionar credenciales, usuario/password para que el equipo de "testing" puedan ingresar a la aplicación sin problema y pueda realizar una revisión. Este punto es importante ya que si no lo realizas tu aplicación puede ser inicialmente rechazada y si se reincide puede darse de baja de Google Play Store.

En este caso comentas :

> Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Android con Firebase como base de
> datos, en la cual el usuario debe registarse con su cuenta de Google
> para acceder a todas las funciones y caracteristicas que tiene la
> aplicación

debes seleccionar la opción "Todas o algunas de las funciones están restringidas" y proporcionar una cuenta y password para "testing".

---

Como no se indicaba mucha información tuve que investigar para estar seguro que opción tomar, revisa :

[**Declarar permisos de una aplicación**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=es)

esto se indica en el punto 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aclarame esto porfavor, ya la subí previamente habiendo seleccionado la primera opción "Todas las funciones disponibles". La app está en la play store, muestra en boton de inicio de sesion de google pero no inicia sesión. Mi pregunta es: solo debo editar ese apartado en la seleccion y proveer correo y password para que el equipo de Google la vuelva a revisar? o debo subir otra vez el archivo .aab ?